# Android: ListView annoyingly scrolling to top when changing between tabs and back

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have a ListView inside of a Fragment attached to a CursorAdapter.  The Fragment has `setRetainInstance(true)`.  Under the Fragment's `onCreate()` method, I instantiate the CursorAdapter (storing it in variable `adapter`).  I then call `listView.setAdapter(adapter)` under my Fragment's `onCreateView` method.  The Cursor in the CursorAdapter is loaded by a CursorLoader.  Inside my LoaderCallbacks' `onLoadFinished()`, I call `adapter.swapCursor(cursor)`.

In sum:  Everything seems to be in place such that the ListView should not scroll to top when changing between tabs and back.  But it still does!  Could I be missing something?

Here's some code.

**Fragment**

```
public class Home extends Fragment{
    ...
    private HomeFeedAdapter adapter; // HomeFeedAdapter extends CursorAdapter
    private AutoQuery autoQuery;     // AutoQuery extends LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
    ...                              // (See inner class, at the end)

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);

        if(adapter == null)
            adapter = new HomeFeedAdapter(getActivity(), null);
        if(autoQuery == null)
            autoQuery = new AutoQuery();
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_INITIAL, null, autoQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false); 
        l = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        l.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }

    private class AutoQuery implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

            ...    
            return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri,
                    null, null, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
            adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
            adapter.swapCursor(null);
        }

    }

}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    ...

    private class TabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private Fragment fragment;
        private String tag;

        public TabsListener(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
            this.fragment = fragment;
            this.tag = tag; 
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.remove(fragment);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Layout
        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Loads fragment
        Fragment fHome, fActivity, fProfile;
        if((fHome = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(HOME)) == null) fHome = new Home();
        if((fActivity = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ACTIVITY)) == null) fActivity = new FriendsList();
        if((fProfile = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(PROFILE)) == null) fProfile = new Profile();       

        ActionBar.Tab tab;
        tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab.setTabListener(new TabsListener(
            fHome,
            HOME
            ));
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab, false);

        tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab.setTabListener(new TabsListener(
            fActivity,
            ACTIVITY
            ));
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab, false);

        tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
        tab.setTabListener(new TabsListener(
            fProfile,
            PROFILE
            ));
        getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab, false);

        ...

    }

}
```

Comment: What does your activity look like?

Comment: My Activity is pretty boilerplate.  It's an instance of `SherlockFragmentActivity`, and creates the Fragments in an inner class of `ActionBar.TabListener`.  I'll try to edit to post some of the Activity code.

Comment: I am betting you create a new fragment and add it newly each time though ;) it's relevant :)

Comment: Posted.  That was a good assumption, but actually I was careful to reutilize the extant Fragment instances.

Comment: you are adding the tab, if it isn't null, aren't you essentially readding it on top of the other fragment that is already there.

Comment: No.  `getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab, false)` adds a graphical tab to the ActionBarSherlock tabs bar; it uses the TabsListener inner class to add the Fragments.  Notice that I use `ft.replace()` in `onTabSelected()`, so there are no superimposed Fragments.  But even if there were I am not sure how that would affect ListView scrolling.

Comment: and hence there is the problem ;)  read up on how fragments work. If a list is recreated from scratch, it will reset its position to zero

Comment: Thanks, but I do not see your point.  Am I not reutilizing an existing Fragment with `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(HOME)`?  That is the Fragment I am passing to the TabListener, and so that is that Fragment that is replacing whatever was there before.  Could you specify?

Comment: the instance doesn't make as much difference as does the lifecycle state imposed by the fragment transaction so like let's say a fragment was added and replaced itself ... what do you think that does to the fragment's lifecycle.  (replace is an add implicitly)

Comment: Well then, what do you propose?  I've tried adding `if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag) != fragment) ft.replace(...);` to no avail.

I think we may be chasing a red herring here.  The ListView is recreated in the Fragment's `onCreateView` every time the screen rotates, but the Adapter isn't recreated.  I thought that would be enough to preserve scroll position.

Comment: ListView instances know of the current positions, adapters do not.

Comment: Thanks, with your help, I've found a solution.  I've posted it below.

Comment: Are you sure, you don't call `listView.setSelection(0)` or somethink like this? You know, some method, which sets to first position (0) your ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Greg Giacovelli's help in leading me in the right direction, I've found a solution to my problem.

I'll begin with a disclaimer that I don't quite understand how ListView positions are saved.  My ListView instance is recreated every time that my Fragment's `onCreateView()` is called.  This happens when the screen rotates, for example.  And yet, in the specific case of screen rotations, even though `onCreateView()` is called and thus the ListView is reinstantiated, the ListView's state is nonetheless restored.  So if the ListView is being recreated, something else must be telling it what its position previously was...  and I don't know what that is.  I think that it's attributable to the machinery of `setRetainInstance(true)`.

But let's look at my main issue: Why did the ListView scroll to top between tab changes?  As Greg suggested, it was because I was re-adding the Fragment with `replace()`, and thus destroying my Fragment and re-creating every time the user flipped to another tab and back.

My solution was to check if the tab was already added; if so, then not add it; else, add it.  Then, when the user clicks out of a tab, I simply detach the fragment (not remove it), and attach a new one.  This way the unselected tab's Fragment is still alive, though detached.

```
// Tabs listener
private class TabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment fragment;
    private String tag;

    public TabsListener(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
        this.tag = tag; 
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(fragment instanceof ScrollableToTop) ((ScrollableToTop) fragment).scrollToTop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(!fragment.isAdded()){
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, tag);
        }
        ft.attach(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.detach(fragment);
    }

}
```